# Compress an HTTP Request in java

Tags: java, compression, httprequest

I want to compress my HTTP request before sending it in java.
how to do please ?
I'm using JBoss4.2 as a Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean "response". See [here](http://www.lucamingardi.com/EN/java_ee_guides/jboss/enable_http_protocoll_compression.php) on how to do it - you have to enable GZIP compression.

Comment: Hey, thnx for your answer :)
I'm sending a big string to a CGI (in delphi) that will put it in the database, so I think if I compress it will be faster, but will CGI understand the compressed request ???

Comment: Surely he does mean request? And the link above is broken.