# How to handle compressed (gzip) HTTP requests (NOT response) in JAVA servlet - Simple Example?

Tags: java, servlets, compression, httprequest, gzip

I struggled with this problem for quite some time; and after finding a simple solution... wanted to ask a question & answer!!

The question has been asked in different ways multiple times on stack overflow, and the `accepted solutions` are either `partially correct and complex` or talk about `response` compression.

**Aggregating some old Q&A on this topic:**

- wrong accepted ans/partially correct & complex
  subsequent ans.

  - [HTTP request compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507007/http-request-compression)
  - [How to decode Gzip compressed request body in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638345/how-to-decode-gzip-compressed-request-body-in-spring-mvc#answer-26226246): (Almost correct 2nd ans, but complex overkill)
- The accepted ans is wrong. It's about `RESPONSE` compression and not `REQUEST`.

  - [Can I compress HTTP Requests using GZIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450151/can-i-compress-http-requests-using-gzip)
  - [Compress an HTTP Request in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370335/compress-an-http-request-in-java)
- Similar Questions - terminated at "NO request compression"

  - [Does Java HTTP Client handle compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502626/does-java-http-client-handle-compression)
- A specific question & ans for Spring RestTemplate framework: [How to zip- compress HTTP request with Spring RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415294/how-to-zip-compress-http-request-with-spring-resttemplate)

Comment: There is a spec draft [RFC7694 Client-Initiated Content-Encoding](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7694.html). Maybe one day it will be accepted as recomended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is by using a filter. ([See servlet-filter tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-filter))

**Create a Servlet Filter:**

- Make sure that the filter is called either first/before any filters which use request body.

**I. Register filter in web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com...pkg...GzipRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

**II. Code for filter class:**

```
public class GzipRequestFilter implements Filter {
    // Optional but recommended.
    private static final Set<String> METHODS_TO_IGNORE = ImmutableSet.of("GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD");

    @Override
    public void doFilter(
            final ServletRequest request,
            final ServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        
        String method = httpServletRequest.getMethod().toUpperCase();
        String encoding = Strings.nullToEmpty(
            httpServletRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING));

        if (METHODS_TO_IGNORE.contains(method) || !encoding.contains("application/gzip")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); // pass through
            return;
        }
        
        HttpServletRequestWrapper requestInflated = new GzippedInputStreamWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        chain.doFilter(requestInflated, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

---

**III. Followed by code for GzipInputStream wrapper:**

```
// Simple Wrapper class to inflate body of a gzipped HttpServletRequest.
final class GzippedInputStreamWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private GZIPInputStream inputStream;

    GzippedInputStreamWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            // NOTE: Later versions of javax.servlet library may require more overrides.
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return inputStream.read();
            }
            public void close() throws IOException {
                super.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    }
}
```

---

Now what remains is how to send a compressed request?

Postman does not yet support sending compressed `HttpRequest` bodies. You can still make it work by using the `binary` option and use a gzipped file containing the properly encoded request body.

One way is using a nodejs script with `pako` [compression library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako). For a multipart/form-data request see `form-data` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)

```
const pako = require('pako')
const axios = require('axios')

var params = qs.stringify({
  'num': 42,
  'str': 'A string param',
});

data = pako.gzip(Buffer.from(params));

var config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Encoding': 'application/gzip';
  },
}

await axios.post(
  'http://url-for-post-api-accepting-urlencoded',
  data,
  config,
).then((res) => {
  console.log(`status: ${res.status} | data: ${res.data}`)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

---

**NOTES:**

- We are using `Content-Encoding: application/gzip` header to specify that a request is compressed. Yes this is standard.
- Do not use `Content-Type` as it will not work with `multipart/form-data`.
- The HTTP protocol has been running under the assumption that size of HttpRequests are dwarfed by  HttpResponses.
- Further, due to assumed limited computing power in browser/client side, the norm has been to compress response and not requests. Browsers cannot natively compress but can do decompression natively.
- But, unfortunately after years of many developers pushing code; some HTTP APIs evolve to consume large strings/data!!
- It's a piece of cake to allow java servlets to have the option of working with compressed requests.