# How can I decompress request on Spring Boot with Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, compression, gzip

I am working with a Spring Boot application with TomCat embedded and I need to decompres the request that I am receiving in gzip. The request is compress with palo.gzip request and returning a type data Uint8array, and I need to decompress.

I have changed the bellow settings on the project

```
server.tomcat.compression=on
```

server.tomcat.compressableMimeTypes=application/json,test/csv, application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
server.compression.enabled=false
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,test/csv, application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain

I have create a filter to decompress the code

```
public class GzipBodyDecompressFilter extends Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    
}
/**
 * Analyzes servlet request for possible gzipped body.
 * When Content-Encoding header has "gzip" value and request method is POST we read all the
 * gzipped stream and is it haz any data unzip it. In case when gzip Content-Encoding header
 * specified but body is not actually in gzip format we will throw ZipException.
 *
 * @param servletRequest  servlet request
 * @param servletResponse servlet response
 * @param chain           filter chain
 * @throws IOException      throws when fails
 * @throws ServletException thrown when fails
 */
@Override
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest,
                           final ServletResponse servletResponse,
                           final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    boolean isGzipped = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING) != null
            && request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING).contains("gzip");
    boolean requestTypeSupported = HttpMethods.POST.equals(request.getMethod());
    if (isGzipped && !requestTypeSupported) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(request.getMethod()
                + " is not supports gzipped body of parameters."
                + " Only POST requests are currently supported.");
    }
    if (isGzipped && requestTypeSupported) {
        request = new GzippedInputStreamWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
@Override
public final void destroy() {
}

/**
 * Wrapper class that detects if the request is gzipped and ungzipps it.
 */
final class GzippedInputStreamWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    /**
     * Default encoding that is used when post parameters are parsed.
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";

    /**
     * Serialized bytes array that is a result of unzipping gzipped body.
     */
    private byte[] bytes;

    /**
     * Constructs a request object wrapping the given request.
     * In case if Content-Encoding contains "gzip" we wrap the input stream into byte array
     * to original input stream has nothing in it but hew wrapped input stream always returns
     * reproducible ungzipped input stream.
     *
     * @param request request which input stream will be wrapped.
     * @throws java.io.IOException when input stream reqtieval failed.
     */
    public GzippedInputStreamWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        try {
            final InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            bytes = new byte[0];
        }
    }


    /**
     * @return reproduceable input stream that is either equal to initial servlet input
     * stream(if it was not zipped) or returns unzipped input stream.
     * @throws IOException if fails.
     */
    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream sourceStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return sourceStream.read();
            }

            public void close() throws IOException {
                super.close();
                sourceStream.close();
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Need to override getParametersMap because we initially read the whole input stream and
     * servlet container won't have access to the input stream data.
     *
     * @return parsed parameters list. Parameters get parsed only when Content-Type
     * "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is set.
     */
    @Override
    public Map getParameterMap() {
        String contentEncodingHeader = getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(contentEncodingHeader)
                && contentEncodingHeader.contains("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) {
            Map params = new HashMap(super.getParameterMap());
            try {
                params.putAll(parseParams(new String(bytes)));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return params;
        } else {
            return super.getParameterMap();
        }
    }

    /**
     * parses params from the byte input stream.
     *
     * @param body request body serialized to string.
     * @return parsed parameters map.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if encoding provided is not supported.
     */
    private Map<String, String[]> parseParams(final String body)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String characterEncoding = getCharacterEncoding();
        if (null == characterEncoding) {
            characterEncoding = DEFAULT_ENCODING;
        }
        final Multimap<String, String> parameters = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        for (String pair : body.split("&")) {
            if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(pair)) {
                continue;
            }
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");

            String key = null;
            if (idx > 0) {
                key = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), characterEncoding);
            } else {
                key = pair;
            }
            String value = null;
            if (idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1) {
                value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), characterEncoding);
            } else {
                value = null;
            }
            parameters.put(key, value);
        }
        return Maps.transformValues(parameters.asMap(),
                new Function<Collection<String>, String[]>() {
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public String[] apply(final Collection<String> input) {
                        return Iterables.toArray(input, String.class);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

}

When I received the request, I am always getting this error :
"Not in GZIP format"

I am debugging and the error is here:

```
CheckedInputStream in = new CheckedInputStream(this_in, crc);
    crc.reset();
    // Check header magic
    if (readUShort(in) != GZIP_MAGIC) {
        throw new ZipException("Not in GZIP format");
    }
```

readUShort(in) is 8752 and it should be GZIP_MAGIC=35615

Do you have some idea why it's not working?

Comment: Basically a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/62784408/2541560